# Blender 2.93 How to hide PNG Reference Image squared areas?

Tags: image

I added a reference image that is PNG. Blender is showing me the squared area too which I'd like to not see. I was looking at similar problems and I think there was a option on object properties tab where you could check "Use Alpha" box. At least in blender 2.93 I dont see that option.
How can I hide those squared areas and just see the object ?

[image: Bowling Pin]

Comment: Hello and welcome, make sure your image really  is a png with transparen backgroud, you should be able to add a png with transparent background by default

Comment: Agreed - I think you have been fooled by Google images. Many of the image results that are "transparent" are, in fact, solid images (no alpha channel) with a checkered background made to resemble a preview of an image with a transparent background (for whatever reason). An image with an alpha channel that is not connected or enabled will have a solid black background (not a checkered one).

Comment: Thank you! That indeed was the case! I did not think to check if that image acctually was png transparent